# function rendering when not needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

sooooo I've been working on a school project with react and firebase.
The problem is I create DOM element with firestore data, but It runs the function no matter the path but I want it to run only when the path is "/journal" and not when it's something else.
here is the app.js

```
import "./styles/base/App.css";
import "./styles/pages/index.css";
import Nav from "./pages/nav";
import Journal from "./pages/journal";
import Authors from "./pages/authors";
import CreateArticle from "./pages/articles/create";
import ArticlesDetails from "./pages/articles/articles pages/articlesdetails";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
          <Route path="/journal" exact component={Journal} />
          <Route path="/articles/create" exact component={CreateArticle} />
          <Route path="/articles/:id" exact component={ArticlesDetails} />
          <Route path="/authors" exact component={Authors} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And this is what renders when the path is "/journal"

```
import "../styles/base/App.css";
import "../styles/pages/journal/Journal.css";
import firebase from "../firebase";
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("articles")
  .limit(4)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      renderArticle(doc);
    });
  });
const articlelist = document.querySelector("#articles");
//create element and render in article page
function renderArticle(doc) {
  let listitem = document.createElement("li");
  let title = document.createElement("h3");
  let author = document.createElement("h6");

  listitem.setAttribute("data-id", doc.id);
  author.textContent = "Wrote by - " + doc.data().author;
  title.textContent = doc.data().title;

  listitem.appendChild(title);
  listitem.appendChild(author);

  articlelist.appendChild(listitem);
} 

function Journal() {
  return (
    <div className="journalbody">
      <header className="journal-header">
        <div className="journal-title">
          <h1>Our Journal</h1>
          <h6>Surf into articles wrote by our students !</h6>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="recent" id="recent">
        <div className="recent-content">
          <h3>Recent Article</h3>
          <a href="#">
            See All articles
          </a>
          <ul id="articles"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
 
      
  );
}
export default Journal;
```

The only problem is it runs the function "renderArticle" when the path is not "/journal" so it messes up the other pages

Sorry for the loads of text and the spells errors and thank you in advance if you have the solution

Comment: well it runs it because `renderArticle` is outside the `Journal`  which is the exported function of the file. Add it inside the function and I guess it will be ok. The `/journal` path renders the `Journal` component which is the `function Journal` exported from your file. `renderArticle` is outside

Comment: also.. maybe you should use react / jsx to render the elements instead of using dom api

Comment: the thing is I am brand new to react and I am just re-making a website I made in html so I still don't really know how to use react jsx.... and When I put renderArticle inside Journal it renders it only when I save the code once the page is reloaded it says that articlelist is null....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a for loop ( over the docs ) directly into the JSX.

Just get your data, add it to your state and then use it in JSX.
see below

Not really sure why the below code returns an error ( first time i tried to use React hooks here ) but you can check the code here -> [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-sg4ms?file=/src/index.js)

```js
function App() {
  const [snapshotDocsState, setSnapShot] = React.useState([]);
   React.useEffect(() => {
    // const snapshot = await db.collection("articles").limit(4).get()
    const snapshot = {
      docs: [
        {
          id: 1,
          author: "First Author",
          title: "Doc 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          author: "Second Author",
          title: "Doc 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          author: "Third Author",
          title: "Doc 3"
        }
      ]
      }
    setSnapShot(snapshot.docs);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="articles">
        {snapshotDocsState.map((doc, index) => (
          <li key={doc.id} data-id={doc.id}>
            <h3>{doc.title}</h3>
            <h6>{doc.author}</h6>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
<div id="root"></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it's just me but it gives me errors,at least not the same but "can't access property "map", snapshotDocsState is undefined".Sorry if it's just me not understanding how to write

Comment: @Setsu does it give you that error in the codesanbox i've provided ?

Comment: no it was in the code I wrote with your code, Idk how to use codesandbox

Comment: well you just open it and edit the code. it autosaves :) you have that error because `snapshotDocsState ` is undefined because you don't assign it the value of your return value from the ' get() ' method. Also i would suggest you use redux and state management for react. That way you can control better what data you have.
Anyway, update the `snapshotDocsState ` with the data you get from the API using the `setSnapShot` method like in my above example

Comment: Any tips on where I can learn redux then ? ^^ and so if I understood I have to put setSnapshot into the '.get()' right ? Sorry if I'm wrong I'm having hard time with english

Comment: You can use ` const snapshot = await db.collection("articles").limit(4).get()`  inside an async useEffect. on `snapshot` you have the response. THen you can do `setSnapshot(snapshot.docs)`   See example here https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data it's exactly what you are looking for. For Redux, there are tons of tutorial on the web

Comment: Thank you mate,helped a lot

Comment: Glad i could help ! please don't forget to upvote my answer. Thank you ! :D

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to make it count : ,-(

Comment: You can accept it ( green tick :) ) but no worries. Good luck with your application ! :D Happy coding